# angular is not posting data to xampp

Tags: javascript, angular

my method for post in angular service is

```
getUserDetails(username , password)
{
  alert(password);
  return this.http.post<myData>("http://localhost/test/api/auth.php", {
  username, password
});
```

}

my php file is like

```
  <?php 
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
  if(isset ($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $possword= $_POST['password'];
  if($username == 'admin' && $password=='adim'){
    ?>
    {
        "success": true,
        "secret": "This is the secret no one knows but the admin"
    }
    <?php } else {
        ?>
        {
            "success": false, 
            "message": "invalid credentials"
        }
        <?php 
    }
    }else {
    ?>
    {
        "success": false,
        "message": "Only POST access accepted"
    }
    <?php 
 }
?>
```

the php file is called but the `username` and `password` does not post data. The first `if` block is not called at all the `else` block is called. 
when I remove the first if statement, then the result is..

```
   <br />
   <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in 
   <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\api\auth.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
   <br />
   <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in 
   <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\api\auth.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
        {
            "success": false, 
            "message": "invalid credentials"
        }
```

Comment: in php you are not returning any values ? also make sure you return it in json format

Comment: how so??????????///

Comment: @joeljoseph I do get the return value from the else part of the first if. it means the value is returned and its in json format.

Comment: did you check the network tab of your browser to see if the request  posted  is  correct  ?

Comment: @joelJoseph I have update the question.  
What do you mean by 'request posted is correct.'

Comment: from your browser right click and inspect element -> click on network tab and  when you submit data to the server from angular  you can view the network calls and check the body and request information to see if you are posting it correct, also you have typo in  php code `possword`

Comment: You have a typo: `possword`..!?

Comment: @Stuart okay I see ... But that does not matter because it does not even enter the first if statement , until I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For php side you can get data something like that...

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

in `$data` you can found your object.

Comment: super!!!  can you tell me how to get the values now. I can see the values posted there.

Comment: for example... `$data->username`